# Spring Hibernate configuration with maven multi module project

Tags: java, spring

Currently I am creating Maven multi-module project with Spring and Hibernate. I am confused where should I have to put `spring-dispature.xml` to access bean configuration. Currently there are `[core-web][core-service(request mapping)][core-bal(bal layer)][core-dal(implementation layer)]` and `[core-model(data access layer)]`.

I have put `applicationContextBalUserProfile.xml` in `core-bal` layer.

```
 <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<!--Scan Merchandising Rest Services for Beans Defined In this Context -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hrcs.bal.userProfile.impl">
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="loginDal" class="com.hrcs.dal.userProfile.impl.LoginDalImpl" />
```

Now where should I have to put View Resolver?

Answer (score 0):

You have an example of an Spring multimodule project here https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs/tree/master/spring-boot-multimodule

(Don't worry if you are not using Spring Boot... is the same idea but without the provided auto-configuration)

Remember that you will have an "application"/"web" module with war packaging. All the other modules should be .jar packages.

That module will be the deployable one that have dependency with the rest of the modules with .jar packaging. (service-api, service-impl, etc.)

All @Configuration classes, .xml configuration files, spring boot starters (if needed), application.properties, etc. must be included on the .war module.

Regards,